# Bloated, hiding and rapid breathing danio

Tags: health, fish

I was wondering if anyone can give any advice about one of my danios. It is a little bloated and keeps hiding in the plants. At one point I noticed it was breathing rapidly. In my tank I also have 3 cardinal tetra and 2 shrimps. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you give more information about your tank? It's size and the parameters of the water (e.g. temperature and nitrite/nitrate levels). Maybe also a picture of the fish if possible?

Comment: Search for Bloat disease in fish, also Dropsy in fish. Find out if the symptoms for these diseases are what your Danio is showing.
Treating it is very very tough, and can be successful only if the disease is caught early.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided enough details about your tank and situation, I can only think of possible causes:-

- The fish may not be getting enough dissolved oxygen.
- The fish may be stressed out due to over-crowding.